# What is the following error: “a.split is not a function” in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an `Angular` application. On the page loading the following error is occurred:

```sh
angular-amin.js:122 TypeError: a.split is not a function
  at r (angular-amin.js:186)
  at m.$digest (angular-amin.js:145)
  at m.$apply (angular-amin.js:148)
  at l (angular-amin.js:101)
  at XMLHttpRequest.t.onload (angular-amin.js:106)
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: where is the code ?

Comment: How are we expected to help you with no context. Please take the time to ask a good question https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score -2):

If ternary operator for ng-class does not has the true, false actions for condition it throws the error. i.e,

```
 ng-class="prop1==1021 || prop1==1031"
```

Change it to

```
 ng-class="prop1==1021 || prop1==1031" ? classA: classB
```